# can I use a compatible action bar AND a fragment in the same activity?

Tags: android

OK, I've been extending my activities to

```
extends ActionBarActivity
```

My main menu page

```
extends FragmentActivity
```

when I change it to extend ActionBarActivity so I can see my action bar title on the main menu, it throws up and gives me the "Error Inflating Class Fragment" error.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

ActionBarActivity [extends](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, so ActionBarActivity serves both purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Is your code from [the Action Bar compatibility example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) that comes with the SDK? If so just change the ActionBarActivity class in that example to extend FragmentActivity (from the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) I assume) instead of Activity.

Comment: -yes, it's from the SDK example.

-when I use 

        extends FragmentActivity

the action bar doesn't show up...

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same problem and the solution, as mentioned in other responses, is to edit your `ActionBarActivity` class.

This class is defined in your code (`com.google.android.actionbarcompat`). The only thing you have to do is change `extends Activity` to `extends FragmentActivity` from the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have menu items for your Fragments? Use your own *`app`* namespace instead of `android` for `app:showAsAction` and `app:actionLayout`, etc.

To add your namespace to the XML use this line in the `menu` tag

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

E.g.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="@string/menu_settings" android:orderInCategory="100" />
</menu>
```

Note the `app:showAsAction` rather than `android:showAsAction`