# Android ActionBar not visible

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-view

I've updated the API 21, tools and extras up to date, the ActionBar in some projects has gone invisible. I did this following code, but app crashes showing NullPointerException.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();
```

Logcat Output

> 02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327): Process: com.example.twaapp, PID: 3327
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twaapp/com.example.twaapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at com.example.twaapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
>   02-23 18:03:36.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3327):     ... 11 more

How to make AB visible?

Comment: can you paste logcat also?

Comment: check the theme for the app

Comment: @vs.thaakur I tried changing theme, but no effect took place

Comment: are you using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`? there is no default action bar for API 21

Comment: Is your Activity extends ActionBarActivity for android.support.v7.appcompact?

Comment: @kishor Joshi, No, my Activity extends FragmentActivity because I use SupportMapFragment in xml to show mapview

Comment: use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your activity extends the `ActionBarActivity`. Like this: `MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`.  I found that when I remove this and extend something else that the action bar would disappear. Also check the theme of the xml and change it.

Check this out:

[can I use a compatible action bar AND a fragment in the same activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040189/can-i-use-a-compatible-action-bar-and-a-fragment-in-the-same-activity)

Comment: AB was visible when I had extended MyActivity with FragmentActivity, recently after update, I lost the AB visibility

Comment: Try to change the theme in your android xml

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 5):

Your `Activity` class should extend like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    ....

}
```

instead of

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    ....

}
```

Also, you need to call

```
ActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

instead of

```
ActionBar = getActionBar();
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: you are right, it is visible after extended by ActionBarActivity :)thanks

Comment: of course that too, for my issue the Ist one is more accurate :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Activity class then your minimum SDK should be greater tahn 13 to show the action bar.Otherwise use ActionbarActivity in Android support Library to make your app backward compatible and use getSupportActionBar() to get the actionbar instance

Comment: Thanks, it is visible after extended by ActionBarActivity :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, `AppCompatActivity` should be used. As-

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

}
```